# How can I change the sort of corelation, it is setting auto for me

Tags: python, pandas-profiling

How can I change the arrange of correlation, it is setting ordinal alpha for me
How can I change the arrange of correlation, it is setting ordinal alpha for me
How can I change the arrange of correlation, it is setting ordinal alpha for me

Comment: Few things here. 1) share the code and sample data set so that others can reproduce it, as stackoverflow is not a free code writing service, we need to see your code and attempt. 2) why is your question repeated 2 times? Clean that up. You need to be posting high quality questions, showing your attempt, and provide an explanation of what you are attempting, with the current output, and what the desired output you are expecting.

Comment: But to answer your question, it doesn't look like you can through the library. You'll either need to go into the code and manually work out adding the option on sorting (it's in the  correlations_pandas.py in the library), or, simply create it individually with pandas and seasborn (which isn't very difficult to do)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I will try better on the next questions